# version relationship between package.json dependencies and build.gradle dependencies?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to understand the version relationship between package.json dependencies and build.gradle dependencies.  For example, I have the following dependency configured in package.json:

```
"firebase-auth": "^0.1.2"
```

I have the corresponding dependency configured in my build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0"
```

I think I had originally installed the firebase-auth package and encountered an error which led me down a path where I googled and determined that the build.gradle dependency above was required.  Based on some more googling, I got lucky with the version 19.1.0 but I really don't know how version dependencies between package.json packages and build.gradle dependency references are correlated.  Can someone here provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `package.json` and `gradle` is the difference between storage.

`package.json` is literally a file for `js`, and the `gradle` is like a repository made to protect `Maven's` shortcomings and `Ant's`.

The relationship between the two is defined when making a module through npm, `build.gradle` has content related to building libraries (such as SDK version), you can find the version here.

The version listed in `package.json` is modified each time an update is made on the github, and depending on the module in the dependency, the link will install the corresponding `android` and `iOS` modules for the version of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Hong.  So let's say that I npm install firebase-auth and the following dependency gets added to my package.json:

"firebase-auth": "^0.1.2",

How can I find the appropriate matching dependency to add to my build.gradle?:

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0"

Comment: You don't have to install it manually. You can install it automatically through the link command.